# PDF at custom points in KDE

Tags: python, r, kernel-density

I am using `density` function in base R to generate KDE for given data vector (1-D). Argument `n` to `density` function gives probability density estimate at `n` uniformly spaced points. Is there a way I can get this estimate at custom list of points?

I am thinking that I want density estimate at every 0.01 percentile point, so that points are closer where they have high density, and farther when not, essentially aligning my PDF estimate to likely confidence of PDF function at that point. This `x,y` collection will be stored and used later for scoring after model development.

Those familiar with Python will recognize that this functionality is available in `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.evaluate(..)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally realised what you meant:

Apparently, you can do it with the `sm` package:

```
library(sm)
a <- rnorm(200)
sm.density(a, eval.points = a)$estimate #the eval.points argument is the key argument you are looking for
```

Output:

```
> sm.density(a, eval.points = a)$estimate
  [1] 0.12772710 0.02405005 0.21971466 0.34392609 0.39495931 0.41543305 0.21263921 0.41537832 0.32914302 0.25565207
 [11] 0.35121705 0.27957087 0.19930803 0.41556843 0.26412647 0.32067182 0.36109746 0.33580489 0.01896655 0.41557119
 [21] 0.10733984 0.30202465 0.39557093 0.10097724 0.13841591 0.34892004 0.38626383 0.07735814 0.04421804 0.39630396
 [31] 0.38700142 0.10177375 0.19136592 0.23634829 0.24060493 0.37283049 0.38447048 0.09277430 0.38300854 0.38747915
 [41] 0.03857675 0.32614202 0.41553740 0.41109807 0.31061776 0.39805191 0.20964930 0.37428245 0.38470874 0.23212350
 [51] 0.37653126 0.06947437 0.39515910 0.40319273 0.41271155 0.24758345 0.40112930 0.41331974 0.29566411 0.39992320
 [61] 0.36686191 0.38990556 0.36492636 0.41281621 0.39267835 0.18448714 0.11787245 0.37712505 0.38775265 0.25030009
 [71] 0.41481836 0.10236957 0.39425025 0.03873721 0.08168519 0.29775494 0.34794457 0.16554033 0.36764219 0.41370926
 [81] 0.39960951 0.41306470 0.11107980 0.27943190 0.41510756 0.35634826 0.36718828 0.38085515 0.15645417 0.25692344
 [91] 0.11179099 0.22799955 0.39206820 0.41408224 0.29348350 0.15890729 0.22721980 0.38384978 0.31640118 0.03881538
[101] 0.41171143 0.41045637 0.38914218 0.40399988 0.38556505 0.27724666 0.15457874 0.36044473 0.21351522 0.37943612
[111] 0.41361048 0.40028703 0.34229100 0.40435532 0.07341782 0.34523757 0.36937555 0.26855928 0.26296213 0.40373905
[121] 0.36823187 0.19218498 0.06875183 0.38383405 0.39380643 0.09261450 0.35676087 0.41512915 0.11002953 0.22801342
[131] 0.12433048 0.13365228 0.35556910 0.37120609 0.33465014 0.41476827 0.30158998 0.41148426 0.40998579 0.29686716
[141] 0.01547056 0.41461764 0.09698607 0.32942869 0.41462633 0.29495019 0.26229083 0.41170128 0.37282610 0.40987606
[151] 0.39528089 0.33079101 0.33618617 0.41054245 0.34696030 0.32505169 0.40190879 0.23373421 0.41092030 0.21069149
[161] 0.41554976 0.37161607 0.09587529 0.23982159 0.40924851 0.28586226 0.04599452 0.41419171 0.34564851 0.37681629
[171] 0.36324057 0.17955626 0.11764356 0.29102065 0.17518755 0.01631140 0.37341812 0.23681565 0.30461539 0.31454744
[181] 0.41112586 0.22881959 0.14398296 0.41454269 0.38818158 0.36846550 0.10876282 0.25267048 0.39286846 0.29270928
[191] 0.14545077 0.34880880 0.40217248 0.32896962 0.41555177 0.33089562 0.41273214 0.08808706 0.39433817 0.06765712
```

So, if you want the 100 quantiles (percentiles) of a:

```
a_quant <- quantile(a, 1:100/100)
sm.density(a_quant, eval.points = a_quant)$estimate
```

Output:

```
> sm.density(a_quant, eval.points = a_quant)$estimate
  [1] 0.01582788 0.06846862 0.08129320 0.10110568 0.11177916 0.11901171 0.12623830 0.14776146 0.15867243 0.16385618
 [11] 0.18902197 0.21554781 0.23069361 0.23686379 0.24233046 0.25667392 0.26330739 0.28597006 0.29260817 0.29466226
 [21] 0.29658942 0.30270500 0.31182163 0.31755901 0.32583914 0.32794022 0.33748016 0.34198509 0.34471986 0.34754376
 [31] 0.35899038 0.36480382 0.36772103 0.37260060 0.37961999 0.38321539 0.38542390 0.38803056 0.39019521 0.39104517
 [41] 0.39212982 0.39676851 0.39976587 0.40359531 0.40668593 0.40756583 0.40814699 0.40892928 0.40930386 0.40967425
 [51] 0.40999673 0.41007634 0.41024728 0.41040236 0.41045483 0.41036411 0.41021185 0.40643714 0.40443569 0.40383346
 [61] 0.40081718 0.39546541 0.39325763 0.39005222 0.38777023 0.38381332 0.37944776 0.37801648 0.37636178 0.37169064
 [71] 0.36890828 0.36603411 0.36374106 0.36101178 0.35648378 0.35354726 0.34896147 0.33874447 0.33061414 0.32493625
 [81] 0.29767821 0.28032682 0.27688973 0.26318047 0.25014308 0.23976716 0.23292234 0.21841618 0.21472566 0.19722509
 [91] 0.16976853 0.13176471 0.11215461 0.10400802 0.09752039 0.08865138 0.07374142 0.04617218 0.04121152 0.02798761

> length(sm.density(a_quant, eval.points = a_quant)$estimate)
[1] 100
```

And this way you can get what you need.

Sorry, I didn't realise what you were asking for at the beginning.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks. 'density' function without default n will provide only 512 estimates. So, length(a$y)=512 in your example. I can increase n, but even then values will be evenly spaced i.e. sd(diff(a$x))=0. I want to be able to get 'y' values for non-even spaced custom list of 'x'. Say, for x=quantile(a, 1:10000/10000)?

Comment: Check this update and let me know if this solves your problem please.

Comment: I am sorry I am not able to explain. You are computing quantiles of `a$x` or `a$y`, while I want quantiles of original data. I mistyped earlier. I should say, `x=quantile(c(-20, rep(0,98), 20), 1:10000/10000)` and want to able to get PDF at those x points.

Comment: I think I got it now. Check this answer and let me know please.

Comment: @LyzrandeR Thanks you. Yes, that's what I needed. I will remember to upvote this and thank in anyway once I reach required "reputation" points!

Comment: Happy I helped :). Took me a while! Please know that you can mark an answer as accepted by clicking the green tick arrow next to an answer. It is always encouraged to mark an answer as accepted if it solves your problem as it shows good manners and also gains you reputation! (accepting is not compulsory). And thanks for your comments! You can check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) for a small induction on accepting answers and generally how the site works!

Comment: Also accepting an answer makes it easier for people who have the same problem as you to be able to find a solution to their problems (if you have confirmed that something works). Thanks!